# How to create scrollable charts in DHTMLX charts

Tags: javascript, html, dhtmlx

Is there any way to create scrollable `DHTMLX Chart`(Bar or Line chart).

As I understood from the code, the chart is drawing in three canvases. 
one for horizontal lines, one for vertical lines and another for the actual chart. So, I am not able to make the chart scrollable.

I can put the total chart into a `DIV` and then I can use `overflow:scroll`.
But with this the y-axis labels will be hidden when I scroll to right side.

Is there any way to draw scrollable charts with `DHTMLX chart`. scrollable means like `DHTMLX Gantt`.

Could you please suggest me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly there is no such functionality in dhtmlxChart. You can only scroll the oughter container.

Answer (score 0):

Dhtmlx Chart has an option to add what they call 'series' (Sample: http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxChart/samples/08_dynamic/01_add.html, what you could try to do is create an event that would control the vertical/horizontal scroll to dynamically add those 'series' creating a fake scroll effect, but i think that's too much work for too little gain.